# iOS navigation color doesn't match view color

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

```
// set the navigation style
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

// set the cancel button color to white
cancel.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// tweet and chars left (140) to white 
tweet.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
charsLeftLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

// set the color of the view containing the above two buttons to the same color as the navigation
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

the view in the navigation and the navigation itself have two different shades although I'm using the same UI Color shades

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try using the following code

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

instead of

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Even the RGB values in the view background is 40, 197, 251 and your navigation bar is having 69, 209, 255

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to set navigation bar and view background colour. :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 29.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: All I had to do was set self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false